# import a sql file using mysql command line tools

Tags: mysql

here is my command to import a sql file into mysql using command line

```
mysql -p eshop < c:\xampp\mysql\eshop.sql
```

But there is error message

```
Error:
Unknown command '\x'

Error:
Unknown command '\m'

Error:
Unknown command '\e'
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with the command?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think this may help you.

`mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql`

check [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html) Options. Don't use `\` (slash) use `/` (slash) to mention the file path.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the pathname separator character is
‘\’, but MySQL treats the backslash as the escape character in strings. To deal with this
issue, write separators in Windows pathnames either as ‘/’ or as ‘\\’. To load a file named
C:\mydata\data.txt, specify the filename as shown in either of the following statements:

```
mysql  <database_name> < ‘C:/mydata/data.txt’
mysql  <database_name> < ‘C:\\mydata\\data.txt’
```